# Express user authentication middleware, how much should it do?

Tags: javascript, express, middleware

I'm trying to learn Express session and authentication handling.

For example:

```
app.post('/login', authCredentials, function(req, res) {
   console.log("second")
});

function authCredentials(req, res, next) {
  //this happens first
  console.log(req.body) // => { username: etc, password: etc }
  next(); 
}
```

My question is just how much should my `authCredentials` function do?
For example if the credentials are correct, I can do something like
`res.redirect('/index')`. Once I do that, however, what purpose does the second function have?

Other questions:

1. How would I handle invalid credentials?
2. If I make `authCredentials` just return `true` or `false` depending on the credentials, doesn't that break the middleware flow because it would never invoke `next()`?
3. Is it possible to access anything in `authCredentials` in the anonymous callback after it? Basically in the `function(req, res) { }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add your `authCredentials` middleware to every end point that needs authentication. `app.post('/login')` usually does not need any as you want to access this end point to actually get credentials in the first place.

When credentials are correct/valid you simply invoke `next()` and the workflow will jump to the next middleware or the actual end point. If there was an error, invoke `next()` with an error object like `next(new Error('could not authenticate');` for instance. Add an error route to your general routing and the error will be handled there:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', err);
});
```

1. Should be answered by now.
2. A middleware does not return a value. It either calls `next()` or ends the process differently by calling `res.send()`.
3. There are different approaches to pass variables from one middleware to another. The most common is probably to attach the desired value to the `req` parameter.

`authenticate` is an asychronous function in the following example:

```
function authCredentials(req, res, next) {
    authenticate(req.body, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, your first example with `app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', err);
});` was just to demonstrate a way to handle an error parameter right? In your second example, `return next(err);`, it's returning the next middleware function down the line?

Comment: An error handling middleware expects 4 parameters instead of the usual 3. If you invoke `next` with a parameter, the error middleware is automatically called. If you have different error handlers, they are called in the same order as they were defined with `app.use`. For more information follow this link: http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: Okay so, calling `next(err)` automatically finds an error middlware. Why do we `return next(err)`, though? I'm guessing the `authenticate` function takes in `req.body` which has the credentials, checks it, then invokes the callback, but that's where I get confused as to what happens with `return next(err);`

Comment: The `return` is just a little trick to stop the whole function from executing right there. When there is an error, we do not want to continue with `req.user = user;` and so on. Of course you can wrap that part in an `else` statement and omit the `return`. This is just for a better readability.

Comment: Oh and also, I forgot I was also confused by why I shouldn't authenticate at `app.post('/login')`. My logic was that, that particular route only gets activated on a POST to that endpoint. When else would the `req.body` have user credentials being sent to the endpoint?

Comment: I didn´t say that you shouldn´t. I said that you usually do not need to for a route that serves that particular purpose. If you want to use `authCredentials` exclusively for that route, why do you use it as a middleware and not as an end point itself?

Comment: Oh so I think I made the mistake of confusing two questions that I had. I guess I wouldn't need to use the logic that `authCredentials` is doing anywhere else in the application other than the login endpoint, so I don't need to separate out a whole middleware. I think what I wanted to know is for how sessions get handled. For example, a user has to be logged in to access certain endpoints. I'm guessing I can do something like `app.use(path, currentUser);` for every path?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on your authentication strategy i.e. are you using session identifiers, access tokens, etc.

In either case I suggest that you break out the credential exchange (aka login) from the authentication.

```
function usernamePasswordExchange(req,res,next){
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;

  callToAuthService(username,password,function(err,user){
    if(err){
      next(err); // bad password, user doesn’t exist, etc
    }else{
      /*
        this part depends on your application.  do you use
        sessions or access tokens?  you need to send the user
        something that they can use for authentication on
        subsequent requests
      */
      res.end(/* send something */);
    }
  });
}

function authenticate(req,res,next){
  /*
    read the cookie, access token, etc.
    verify that it is legit and then find
    the user that it’s associated with
  */
  validateRequestAndGetUser(req,function(err,user){
    if(err){
      next(err); // session expired, tampered, revoked
    }else{
      req.user = user;
      next();
    }
  });
}

app.post('/login',usernamePasswordExchange);

app.get('/protected-resource',authenticate,function(req,res,next){
  /*
    If we are here we know the user is authenticated and we
    can know who the user is by referencing req.user
  */
});
```

Disclaimer: I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and we spend a lot of time writing
authentication code :) I just wrote our newest library, [stormpath-sdk-express](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-express),
which has a concrete implementation of my suggestions